# Is it possible to programmatically add line breaks inside \makecell?

Tags: line-breaking, makecell

I've found myself in a situation where I need to dynamically add a list of strings inside a `tabular` cell in multiple instances, each string in their own line. To tackle this, I tried to go with the following approach, using the `makecell` and `forarray` packages:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{forarray}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\listcontacts}[1]{\ForEach{,}{\scriptsize\textbf{\thislevelitem}\\}{#1}}

\begin{tabular}{ r r }
    \hline
    \textbf{NAME} & \textbf{CONTACT} \\ 
    \hline
    John Doe & \makecell[r]{\listcontacts{Number One,Number Two,Number Three}} \\ % Error: Tried to expand an \endforeachtoken. Something is wrong.
    \hline
\end{tabular}

\listcontacts{Number One,Number Two,Number Three} % renders fine

\end{document}
```

[image]

As you can see, the list renders fine outside of the table, but behaves strangely inside `makecell` due to the programmatically added line breaks, on top of an error thrown at the affected line. Using anything different than a line break, it renders fine inside the cell as well.

I already tried to use `pgfmath` as an alternative way to iterate, as well as `\StrSubstitute` from the `xstring` package to downright replace the commata with line breaks. Even line breaks in the command parameter itself won't be processed correctly by `makecell`.

This leaves me wondering, is there any way to add line breaks inside `makecell` besides to do so statically? How would I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using L3's `\clist_map_inline:nn` instead of `forarray` this works as intended. The issue is that each line in `\makecell` forms a cell in a nested `tabular`, and hence is a group. It seems the loop of `forarray` doesn't cope with that well.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{makecell}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand \listcontacts { m }
  { \clist_map_inline:nn {#1} { \scriptsize \textbf {##1} \\ } }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ r r }
    \hline
    \textbf{NAME} & \textbf{CONTACT} \\ 
    \hline
    John Doe & \makecell[r]{\listcontacts{Number One,Number Two,Number Three}} \\ % Error: Tried to expand an \endforeachtoken. Something is wrong.
    \hline
\end{tabular}

\listcontacts{Number One,Number Two,Number Three} % renders fine

\end{document}
```

But this way we get an additional `\\` at the end, which causes `\makecell` to display an empty line at the bottom. To get rid of that we need to treat the first row differently from the others (or the last row, but that would be harder to implement). Additionally, if you use your macro as it is outside of a `tabular` the `\scriptsize` would leak and affect the other stuff, so we put it into the argument of `\textbf` to keep it local.

Everything sticked together looks like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{makecell}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\seq_new:N \l_strikeagainst_contacts_seq
\NewDocumentCommand \listcontacts { m }
  {
    \seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l_strikeagainst_contacts_seq {#1}
    \seq_pop_left:NNT \l_strikeagainst_contacts_seq \l_tmpa_tl
      {
        \textbf { \scriptsize \l_tmpa_tl }
        \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_strikeagainst_contacts_seq
          { \\ \textbf { \scriptsize ##1 } }
      }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ r r }
    \hline
    \textbf{NAME} & \textbf{CONTACT} \\ 
    \hline
    John Doe & \makecell[r]{\listcontacts{Number One,Number Two,Number Three}} \\ % Error: Tried to expand an \endforeachtoken. Something is wrong.
    \hline
\end{tabular}

\listcontacts{Number One,Number Two,Number Three} % renders fine

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you a lot, this worked excellently!